# Laravel not working openssl extension issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.3.30. I am trying to use authentication in my project.

But when try to register it gives me error:

> FatalErrorException in Encrypter.php line 73:Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt().

I have enabled openssl extension in `php.ini` and confirmed it through `phpinfo` but still when I try to register it gives error regarding `openssl_encrypt`. Please Help

Comment: Was you PHP compiled with openssl? If  not you'll need to recompile. See; http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Comment: I have tried this but didn't work.

Comment: Can you give more details about your environment please. E.g OS, PHP Version

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I checked my php path in environment variable which was to other older php folder and I was changing openssl extension of php.ini file of another new php folder. So, I changed the php path in environment folder to point to new folder and it worked!